# Is the trigger of a drill a potentiometer?

Tags: electrical-engineering

How does the trigger of a typical modern multi speed drill (maybe Ryobi for example) work? Is it just a potentiometer? Or is it more involved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I opened a Ryobi type of cordless drill. The control appeared to be a potentiometer connected to a PWM circuit module which varied the duty cycle of the power applied to the motor.

Comment: Ahh, a true engineer :-).  Never look up a datasheet when you have an excuse to take something apart!

Comment: Oh yes, some of us were taking things apart before we could read : note no mention of getting them back together again....